# Deleting a role (discord.py rewrite)

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

right now I'm trying to make a command to delete a role and I'm trying to go off of what I used to create a role

```
@client.command()
async def createrole(ctx):
guild = ctx.guild
await guild.create_role(name="role")
```

and I can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete a role, you need to do a bit more work than with creating a role. You would need to use the `delete` function in the `Role` object. So if you wanted to create a command named "delete role", you would need to first get the role object before you delete it. You could do that with the following:

```
@client.command(name="delete_role", pass_context=True)
async def delete_role(ctx, role_name):
    #find role object
    role_object = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name=role_name)
    #delete role
    await role_object.delete()
```